# pyautogui try locateonscreen for 30 seconds

Tags: python, pyautogui

I use Python 3.x.
I made a script to locate an image on screen and if it doesn't find it after x seconds it skip and do something else but it currently doesn't work ...
Here is code

```
def finditbaby(path):
    endtime = time.time() + 10 #only 10 second for test
    image = None
    while (image is None) and (time.time() < endtime):
        image = pyautogui.locateOnScreen(path)
```

Thats the function and here is how I use it :

```
finditbaby(path.png)
if image is not None:
    print("image found")
    click on image
```

but it doesn't work, it always print image found even when image is not on screen :(

Answer (score 1):

```
def finditbaby(path):
    endtime = time.time() + 10 #only 10 second for test
    while time.time() < endtime:
        if pyautogui.locateOnScreen(path) != None:
            print("image found")
            # click on image 
            break
```

maybe you can change to this... you don't need declare a variable to image I guess